# How does Hyperledger Fabric avoid infinite loop?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, ethereum

There is 'gas' in Ethereum and Bitcoin doesn't support loop at all, I am curious how does Hyperledger Fabric avoid infinite loop?

Answer (score 5):

Hyperledger Fabric does not use gas, but it does address the halting problem by setting a timeout for chaincode execution. The chaincode container will be killed if the transaction does not execute within the configured timeout as specified by the `chaincode.executetimeout` property.

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is no mechanism to stop infinite loops. There is an open issue in github, https://github.com/hyperledger-archives/fabric/issues/2232 so its possible that it is coming.

Hyperledger Fabric is not intended to be a public blockchain and smart contracts are not intended to be uploaded by any user. They are intended to be developed by an internal team and tested these scenarios.

Comment: the referenced defect is against an archived version of Fabric that is no longer being developed.